# Использование функции GetDriveType()

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

При написании приложения Visual C++, формирующего список логических дисков и определении их типа, функция GetDriveType() любой из дисков, будь-то CDROM, или съемный, определяет как локальный. Информацию по данной проблеме так и не смог найти. Может кто-нибудь подскажет в чем проблема с этой функцией. Операционная система - Windows 10.

Comment: Где среди возвращаемых значений `GetDriveType` Вы нашли "Local Drive"?

Comment: DRIVE_FIXED. Но важно то, что не определяет верно тип дисков, отличных от жесткого

Comment: А на WinXP/Win7 этот же код будет работать корректно?

Comment: К сожалению не проверял на WinXP/Win7. Но хотелось бы чтоб в десятке работало.

Comment: То есть Вы утверждаете, что с данными https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa364939(v=vs.85).aspx у вас не сходится?

Comment: Не сходится результат работы функции. Возможно в Win7 она отработает правильно. Но под рукой нет другой системы, кроме десятки